# OnKeyDown in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, onkeydown

I want launch a scanner for read a QR code when user press a specific button (volume). I override OnKeyDown event, but when the event finish the app starts an 'interrupt mode'.

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {            
        switch (keyCode)
        {
            // in smartphone
            case Keycode.VolumeUp:
                ReadQr();
                break;
                //return true;

            // in glasses
            case Keycode.DpadRight:
                ReadQr();
                break;                    
                //return true;
        }            
        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
private async Task<string> ReadQr()
    {
        QRScanner QRcode = new QRScanner();
        var result = await QRcode.ScanQR();

        UDPmanager clienteUDP2 = new UDPmanager(IPAddress.Broadcast.ToString(), _port);
        clienteUDP2.ClientWrite(result.ToString());

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why did you comment `return true;`?

Comment: Because is not necessary, with break is inaccessible

Comment: Can you show me the `ReadQr()` code? Does running it directly work?

Answer (score 0):

> but when the event finish the app starts an 'interrupt mode'.

I think you mean Break Mode. Your code for the keys look fine. I would recommend you to check your `ReadQr()`, I am pretty sure that your error will be in that part of your application.

Comment: Sorry, lost in traslation :P Yes, it's break mode. I updated my 1st post with ReadQR function.

Comment: Put your method in a `try/catch`, if it doesn't enter Break Mode, you will know that the error is in there.

Comment: The method works fine, the problem is keydown because it finish before the scanner is launched. I tried awaiting until scanner reads something but screen turns black. I think because is in the middle of keydown event and it has come kind of problem with GUI :S

Comment: What about `ReadQr().Wait()`, it will block the operation till the QR method is done. Did you try that?

Comment: Yep, i tried. Is that thing i said about the black screen.